# what is the scope and visibility of TempData in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'd like to know what the scope and visibility of TempData is in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to MSDN, TempData, an instance of [TempDataDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx), is available in classes that derive from [ControllerBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.tempdata.aspx), [ViewContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.tempdata.aspx), and [ViewPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.tempdata.aspx).  The data only lasts for a single round-trip: set in one request, removed after the next request.

Answer (score 15):

For others... ASP.NET MVC 2 has made some changes to TempData. Here is a [blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/jacqueseloff/archive/2009/11/17/tempdata-improvements.aspx) with details. In summary:

...The outcome of the changes we made resulted in the following rules that govern how `TempData` operates:

1. Items are only removed from `TempData` at the end of a request if they have been tagged for removal.
2. Items are only tagged for removal when they are read.
3. Items may be untagged by calling `TempData.Keep(key)`.
4. `RedirectResult` and `RedirectToRouteResult` always calls
   `TempData.Keep()`.

Answer (score 1):

TempData is not accessible (set to null) in Views using post-cache substitution (HttpResponse.WriteSubstitution() Method). See [ASP.NET MVC "Donut caching" and TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683646/asp-net-mvc-donut-caching-and-tempdata) for more details.