# TempData become null when secure asp.net_sessionid from Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using TempData in my project and when Redirect to particular action using RedirectToAction my TempData become **null**.This is because I have secured asp.net_sessionid in Global.asax using following code.

```
var sessionCookieKey = Response.Cookies.AllKeys
    .SingleOrDefault(c => c.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid");
var sessionCookie = Response.Cookies.Get(sessionCookieKey);
if (sessionCookie != null)
{
    sessionCookie.Secure = true;
}
```

So please help me how can I persist the Tempdata value.

Comment: Are you reading your tempdata value in between. If yes you need to say to persist it once you read like `TempData.Keep("YourKey")`

Comment: I have tried with this but it will not work.Also I have not read the value in between.

Comment: check **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683646/asp-net-mvc-donut-caching-and-tempdata)**

Comment: The code in above link only works when session-cookie not secure but in my case it is secure.